# Setting value to bootstrap datapicker object

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I use bootstrap datepicker object http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker

HTML

```
             <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                 <input type='text' class="form-control" value="" />
                 <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                 </span>
             </div>
```

In JS file

```
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     format: 'l',
     locale:$.fn.getlocale(),
     showTodayButton:true,
     maxDate:moment().add(6, 'month')
 });
```

On page loading, I want to set a date that is provided by mysql back end. I tried the following code and I don't see any date being shown in the UI.

```
    var backend_date = dataset["APPLICATION_DEADLINE"];
    var date = new Date(backend_date);
    $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date(moment(date));
```

Could you please help?

Comment: the lisk redirects to 404 page

Comment: try echoing the date in the input field

Comment: `dataset["APPLICATION_DEADLINE"]` is this php variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found an easy way

```
var dateobj = $.fn.getDateObjectFromMYSQL(dataset["APPLICATION_DEADLINE"]);
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date(dateobj);
```

---

```
$.fn.getDateObjectFromMYSQL = function(mysqldate){
    var t = mysqldate.split(/[- :]/);
    var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var backend_date = dataset["APPLICATION_DEADLINE"];
var date = new Date(backend_date);
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
       defaultDate: date
});
```